How to return Cell Reference of DataGridView if Value in that Cell Matches with Textbox?
I would like to get the reference to a Cell - i.e. the row and column numbers, or the cell address of the particular cell if that DataGridView cell contains the value of a Textbox.
I've explored many URLs to get what I desire. I even might have missed visiting the URLS as may be asked in a different manner.
Dim colNdx As Integer
Dim rowNdx As Integer

Dim IsFound As Boolean = False
For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        If rw.Cells(i).Value.ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
            IsFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
If (IsFound) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Data Exists! in Cell of DataGridWiew1" & )
    DataGridView1.Rows(rowNdx).Cells(colNdx).Value
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Data Not Exists!")
End If

So How can I have the cell reference of rw.Cells(i).Value.ToString(), for example, displaying the row and column numbers of that cell which exists in the DataGridView and is matched with the Textbox?
I tried the above code but could not set it properly to get the cell reference.

Well in your code you never set rowNdx or colNdx. So DataGridView1.Rows(rowNdx).Cells(colNdx).Value won't work in the MessageBox, even if that piece of code didn't have syntax issues.
Write a function to retrieve the cell, or null if it's not found.
Private Function FindString(dgv As DataGridView, searchString As String) As DataGridViewCell
    For Each row In dgv.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)
        For Each cell In row.Cells.OfType(Of DataGridViewCell)
            If cell.Value.ToString() = searchString Then
                Return cell
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

And call it like this
Dim cell = FindString(DataGridView1, TextBox1.Text)
If cell IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show($"Data exists in cell ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex})")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Data does not exist!")
End If


djv Thanks for your great help. Indeed Cell reference of DGV is returned of String/Textbx.matched value.
What if we wanted Full List of
Cell{cell.rowIndex}, {cell.ColumIndex}) ie for the below grid
6 9 7
8 1 5
2 4 3
Dim numbers As String() = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}
and get list like below
6 is in cell (0,0)
9 is in cell (0,1)
7 is in cell (0,2)
4 is in cell (2,4) etc

@SsD I understand. However, your question does not ask for that. Even before I fixed some of your formatting, there is no mention of cells or matches in your question - only singular. So I have answered your question. There is also no attempt at multiple matches in your code, so there's no way anyone would answer your question according to your comment. Sorry! You can pose a new question which includes an attempt at that problem.

djv Yes Agreed let me work on this and post new question Thanks
